# Calculate the potential and current in the transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I'm stuck on a question where I need to calculate the potential V<sub>x</sub> and the current I<sub>x</sub> in the circuit below. I have managed to get some equations, but the question does not mention what the amplification factor h<sub>FE</sub> is, only that it is "high", so I can't solve the question with what I have.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: the circuit in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an emitter resistor of 10k the circuit has relatively strong negative feedack. Therefore, the actual value of VBE is relatively unimportant - you can assume VBE=0.7 volts (This - blind - assumption will have very little influence on the result) - in partular, because you are allowed to set the base current to zero (IB=0), in accordance with the simplification of a "very high" value of hfe.

As a consequence, finding the emitter current (equal to the collector current) is a very simple task - there is no voltage drop across the base resistor and we have Vx=Vbase and Vemitter=Vx-0.7 volts.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with a detailed analysis but do some quick mental arithmetic. If the transistor were to turn on as much as it could:

1. What is \$ V_{be} \$?
2. Then what is \$ V_{ce} \$ (assuming negligable little base current)?
3. Given that the supplies and the load resistances are symmetrical what is the voltage on c and e?

That will give you a reality check when you solve your equations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyafy1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. You can run the DC solver on this schematic. Carefully edit the question, edit the schematic and run the Simulation | DC Solver. Don't save on exit.*